# Running shell script in detached screen session. Must kill. How?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I am an Ubuntu Linux user.  I am running jobs remotely and started a screen session.  During this session I sourced a file containing a long list of command lines arguments to be executed.  I was forced off of the connection and now the jobs are still running in this screen and I am unable to kill them.

Does anyone know how to kill all running and future commands this script will execute.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reattach the screen with

```
screen -D -r
```

then you can resume your session.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  I have another question.  Within the context of this solution, when I reattach to my screen session:

Without holding Ctrl-C until all commands abort, is there a faster way to kill all future commands in one swoop?

Comment: Screen's manual would have told you that C-a C-k destroys the current window, which should take the shell and all future commands with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to kill everything there is no need to even reattach to screen.

Just list the offending process(es):

pstree -pla

then kill whatever needs killing. Note that if you kill a process higher up the process tree, its children will (usually) go away as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use ps to identify the pid of the shell process (bash, tcsh, etc), then kill that...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of 'screen' ways to kill a specific screen session ...

1) send a 'quit' command:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" quit
```

2) send a Ctrl-C to a screen session running a script:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" stuff "^C"
```

In both cases, you would need to use 'screen -ls' to find the session name of the screen session you want to kill ... if there is only one screen session running, you won't need to specify the -S "sessionname" parameter.